# Compiled failed when import java class in groovy

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, task

I want to define a `gradle` custom task. This is the structure:

```
├── buildSrc
│   ├── buildSrc.iml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── groovy
│               └── com
│                   └── gocd
│                       └── CustomTask.groovy
| -- build.gradle
```

In the CustomTask.groovy file:

```
import com.mongodb.Mongo
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
import org.mongeez.Mongeez
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource

class CustomTask extends DefaultTask {

  @TaskAction
  def upgradeMongo() {
    Mongeez mongeez = new Mongeez()
    mongeez.setFile(new ClassPathResource("mongeez.xml"))
    mongeez.setDbName("local_pipeline")
    mongeez.setMongo(new Mongo("127.0.0.1", 27017))
    mongeez.process()
}

}
```

And I declarate a gradle task in build.gradle file:

```
task updateMongo(type: CustomTask)
```

,After that, I run **gradle build**, the error is:

```
/fgcui/myProject/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/gocd/CustomTask.groovy: 3: 
unable to resolve class com.mongodb.Mongo
@ line 3, column 1.
import com.mongodb.Mongo
^

/Users/fgcui/myProject/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/gocd/CustomTask.groovy: 6: 
unable to resolve class org.mongeez.Mongeez
@ line 6, column 1.
import org.mongeez.Mongeez
^

/Users/fgcui/myProject/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/gocd/CustomTask.groovy: 7: 
unable to resolve class org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource
@ line 7, column 1.
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource
^

3 errors

:buildSrc:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Does what I did wrong?

Comment: What did you specify in buildscript / dependencies? Are the missing libraries in there?

Comment: @Henry In dependencies, I add **compile ('org.mongeez:mongeez:0.9.6')
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.10')
    compile group: 'org.gradle', name: 'gradle-core', version: '3.1'**